# how to create .exe file in visual studio 2017 for 1 project of selenium using c# having multiple class within it

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a project where I am writing selenium script. I'm writing it in visual studio 2017.I am using c#, NUNIT framework with selenium. I am having several classes. Each class is testing functionality of each page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSn8d.png).1 class i.e Login class is kept as parent class and other classes are inheriting that to login to the web page. I want to run the test outside visual studio from command prompt by creating a .exe file for each class. In 1 single project I kept all the class files.how to create **.exe** file in visual studio 2017  for 1 project of selenium using c# having **multiple class** within it.

Answer (score 0):

Select Release from the Solution Configuration drop-down list, which is on the Standard toolbar.
On the Build menu, click Build.

Comment: Please specify the exact location.I am not finding Release. Will this help me in creating separate exe  file so that I can run the class outside visual studio?

Comment: I selected Release and clicked on build .But nothing happened.It didnot make any difference.

Comment: you can find it under your visual studio project folder in release folder there will be a .exe file of your project

Comment: under visual studio project bin\Release\ you will get the executable

Comment: I tried to open it from there but its not opening. The command prompt is opening and closing immediately. As I'm having several classes and only 1 exe file is there. So, I think its not opening. I tried to create separate exe file for each of the classes but its not happening. what to do? Please help.

Comment: This doesn't apply to UWP apps. They need a container.